# Generating a better ctags file for Rails projects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, vim, emacs, ctags

How can I generate a good ctags file for a rails project ? One that includes all the gems, ruby libs and sorts them in the right order (like when you search for “Rails” it doesn’t go to the airbrake gem or whatever)

I'm using this right now, but I don't like it for the reason mentioned above:

```
ctags --tag-relative -Rf.git/tags.$$ --exclude=.git --exclude=*.html --exclude=tmp --exclude=public --exclude=app/assets --languages=-javascript,js,sql,html `bundle show --paths` $MY_RUBY_HOME .
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out the better option (better than ctags) is either [Robe](https://github.com/dgutov/robe) for Emacs or a combination of `vim + tmux + vmux + pry` (to get `show-source` and `edit`).

[irb-config](https://github.com/nviennot/irb-config) is an interesting example of vim setup.

Answer (score 1):

Neither Vim nor ctags understand or can be taught to understand your code and/or your thoughts. If you want to jump to a different tag than the first matching one in your `tags` file, use the proper commands:

```
:tselect foo        " list all tags 'foo'
:tselect /foo       " list all tags containing 'foo'
g]                  " list all tags matching the word under your cursor
```

Also, note that you can make "your" ctags command a little shorter by whitelisting filetypes:

```
ctags --tag-relative -Rf.git/tags.$$ --exclude=.git --exclude=tmp --exclude=public --exclude=app/assets --languages=ruby `bundle show --paths` $MY_RUBY_HOME .
```

Comment: Any other solution would do, I don't really care what it is. I see pry  does it, I just need to figure out how to make it work with vim.

Comment: Ask your real question, then: "How can I make Vim's jump to definition smarter for Ruby?". You can try [Ripper](https://github.com/tmm1/ripper-tags) to generate your `tags` but that won't make Vim smarter when using that file.

Comment: I did try ripper and I didn't see any improvement.

Comment: Indeed. Please rephrase your question or ask another one.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I'm doing and it works okay:

```
#!/bin/bash

project_dir="~/<project>"

# Delete existing tags to start fresh
rm -f tags gemtags evrthngelse

# Generate tags for Ruby gems
ripper-tags -R -f gemtags <path to project gemfile>/gems

# Generate tags for the project, excluding certain directories and files
ctags -R -f evrthngelse --exclude=vendor --exclude=.git --exclude=log --exclude=tmp --exclude='*.rb' --exclude='*.erb' .
ripper-tags -R --exclude=vendor --exclude=.git --exclude=log --exclude=tmp .

# Concatenate temporary tag files into the main 'tags' file
cat evrthngelse >> tags
cat gemtags >> tags

# Remove temporary tag files
rm -f gemtags evrthngelse

# De-duplicate the tags file, preserving order
awk '!seen[$0]++' tags > temp_tags && mv temp_tags tags
```

I know the root issue is Ruby's loosey goosey dynamic class/module/method definitions, but it still feels like it should work better. I was hopeful for ripper-tags, but it's a lot worse than an IDE in terms of predicting which tag definitions you want to go to.